# OS X Vagrant host unable to connect to Apache/Passenger Server on Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, apache, redirect, vagrant

## Unsuccessful redirects from Vagrant guest to host

I am trying to configure a [Yosemite **Vagrant** box](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/jhcook/boxes/osx-yosemite-10.10/versions/10.10.5) to work with my Yosemite machine. I have a **Ruby 1.8.7/Rails 2** (you read correctly) application running on top of **Passenger** with the **Apache** module. I'm very new to both servers and Vagrant, and I'm struggling to share the Vagrant box's application on my host machine, even though I've verified the guest environment by connecting to the GUI (VirtualBox) and navigating to the dev site via Chrome. **I suspect it's something to do with the redirects in my apache config**, and I'll demonstrate why.

Here's my apache config (**/etc/apache2/other/[my_custom].conf**).

*Note the `RedirectPermanent` lines, as well as the separate codebases that we are serving*:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.59/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
 PassengerRoot /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-4.0.59
 PassengerDefaultRuby /Users/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby
</IfModule>

LogFormat "%h %p %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"

<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName [servername].dev
 RedirectPermanent / "http://www.[servername].dev/"
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName [subdomain1].[servername].dev
 ServerAlias [subdomain2].[servername].dev
 RailsEnv development
 DocumentRoot /Users/vagrant/code/[codebase1]/public
 <Directory /Users/vagrant/code/[codebase1]/public>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
 RedirectPermanent /[subdomain1] "http://[subdomain1].[my_servername].dev"
 RedirectPermanent /[subdomain2] "http://[subdomain2].[my_servername].dev"
 Include /Users/vagrant/code/[codebase1]/config/php/httpd/passenger_routes.conf
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.[servername].dev
 RailsEnv development
 DocumentRoot /Users/vagrant/code/[codebase2]/public
 <Directory /Users/vagrant/code/[codebase2]/public>
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
 </Directory>
 RedirectPermanent /[subdomain1] "http://[subdomain1].[my_servername].dev"
 RedirectPermanent /[subdomain2] "http://[subdomain2].[my_servername].dev"
 Include /Users/vagrant/code/[codebase2]/config/php/httpd/passenger_routes.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/hosts** file on my Vagrant box:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
255.255.255.255  broadcast
::1              localhost
127.0.0.1        www.[servername].com
127.0.0.1        [subdomain1].[servername].com
```

**Vagrantfile**:

```
# -​*- mode: ruby -*​-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.vm.box = "jhcook/osx-yosemite-10.10"
 config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080,
   auto_correct: true    
end
```

## Things I've tried:

1. When I boot up apache in the Vagrant box and navigate to
   `www.[servername].com` or `[subdomain1 or 2].[servername].com`, the
   site comes up as expected.  However, when I go to the host machine
   and navigate to `http://localhost:8080`, the request times out after
   hanging for about 2 min.
2. When I `curl -i "http://localhost:8080"` on my host machine, I get

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
   Date: Wed, 07 Oct 2015 19:44:27 GMT
   Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) Phusion_Passenger/4.0.59 PHP/5.5.27
   Location: http://www.[servername].dev/
   Content-Length: 227
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
   <html><head>
   <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
   </head><body>
   <h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
   <p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.[servername].dev/">here</a>.</p>
   </body></html>
   ```

And when I `curl -i "http://www.[servername].dev"`, the terminal hangs for about 2 minutes and finally returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.[servername].dev port 80: Operation timed out`. However, when I navigate my VirtualBox GUI to www.[servername].dev, the page is served up fine.

3. I checked the apache logs, and the requests to `localhost:8080` on my host machine are not registering, so my suspicion is that there's something about the redirect and reserved ports that's preventing my host machine from accessing this app.
4. Quick list of other things I've tried (glad to explain further if needed):

   - Successfully verified that a different app can be accessed via host
     machine (used port 3000 for a Rails API, 8988 for Solr admin panel .
     . . )
   - Vagrantfile `private_network`: same general problems (curling get's a redirect, going to redirect URL hangs)
   - Assigning new port in my apache config (eg 9000): same problems, new port
   - Assigning set IP address in apache config (eg 10.10.0.0) with and without Vagrantfile `private_network`: same problems, new IP
   - Tried the Vagrantfile without `auto_correct`
   - Tried the port forwarding with `guest: 80, host: 80` with no success
5. I'm trying to avoid using `vagrant share` in any way, so that this box is a little more self-contained.

### Does anyone have experience working with redirects in Apache inside a Vagrantbox?

### How can I get my guest to forward the redirect to the host as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, poking, prodding, I realized that I never updated my *host machine* **/etc/hosts** file. Adding these two lines has allowed the port forwarding (`guest: 80, host: 8080`) to work:

```
127.0.0.1        www.[servername].com
127.0.0.1        [subdomain1].[servername].com
```